# nestjs save each request info without hitting database twice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, request, nestjs

I want to save each request (path, method, and userId) that comes to the server without having to hit the database twice, and also without messing up the main logic in services files with transactions.

Initially, I was trying to use an **interceptor** because it gets invoked after auth **guards** "which attaches the user to request" and before request handlers, but I faced two issues.
first, the fact that the interceptor will call the database to save a new record and then forward the request to handlers which will again hit DB again to handle the request. Secondly, It didn't work anyway because of dependancy injection problems.

code below is not working due to dependency errors as I mentioned, but It will give u an idea about what I need to acheive.

```js
import { Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
  Inject,
  ExecutionContext,
  CallHandler,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { HistoryEntity } from '../../modules/history/history.entity';

@Injectable()
export class HistoryInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(
    @Inject(getRepositoryToken(HistoryEntity))
    private readonly historyRepo: Repository<HistoryEntity>
  ) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const { user, path, method } = request
    if (!user) {
      throw new HttpException('something terrible happened!', HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
    }

    const history = this.historyRepo.create({
      path,
      userId: user.id,
    });

    this.historyRepo.save(history);

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

PS. from a performance point of view, It would also be great to not halt the request execution to save these info in db, in other words, Is it ok to NOT use **await** in this particular situation? because essecntially this is a system related operation and so, Node [rocess shouldn't wait for this step to process and return response to client.

Thanks in advance.